# Inserir usuario e senha em arquivo bat

Tags: batch

Tenho um arquivo .bat que faz uma copia de arquivos de um servidor para outro, automaticamente. Estamos atualizando o ambiente e esse servidor sera modificado e ao testar o .bat recebi o seguinte erro:

```
Falha de logon: nome de usuário desconhecido ou senha incorreta.
```

Existe como passar usuario e senha em um comando como o abaixo?

```
@echo INICIO VENDAS
@echo.

copy \\192.168.203.130\ebsout\*.txt c:\wamp\www\SIG\ /y
```

Comment: Já tentou algo como `NET USE X: \\IP do Servidor\PASTA senha /USER:usuario /PERSISTENT:NO`?

Comment: @diegofm testei esse comando e deu o erro: "A Senha de rede especificada nao esta correta", mesmo a senha estando correta. Vou tentar baixar os dois servidores para ver o que acontece.

Answer (score 1):

> > Considerando que o sistema possa estar querendo usar o seu usuário logado na autenticação do comando, posso sugerir que tente 1x usando a senha do usuário logado, não a que pretendes usar no comando, caso confirme o que estou entendendo, fica abaixo uma sugestão como alternativa para tentar contornar esse evento:
> >
> > **`É possível usando o SendKey (VBS) para enviar os dados de entrada`**

**<kbd>`Abaixo um exemplo usando telnet com inserção de dados`</kbd>**

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> Apenas **substituir** nas linhas abaixo os **respectivos valores** para as **variáveis**:
>
> ***[_usuario_]  [_senha_]  [_cmd_]***
>
> *set "_usuario_=**usuario-x**" & set "_senha_=**senha-y**"*
>
> *set "_cmd_=**copy \192.168.203.130\ebsout*.txt c:\wamp\www\SIG\ /y**"*

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & mode 60,20 & color 9F

echo/INICIO VENDAS & echo/ & mode con cols=77 lines=30

set "_usuario_=cisco_user" & set "_senha_=4LoCk007XSwT001"
set "_cmd_=telnet.exe 192.168.0.254"

>"%temp%\_temp_file_4vbs_.vbs"^
    (
     echo/ Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)
     echo/ Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)
     echo/ StrPwd  = "!_senha_!"
     echo/ StrUser = "!_usuario_!"
     echo/ for i=1 To Len^(StrUser^)
     echo/     x = Mid^(StrUser,i,1^)
     echo/     WshShell.SendKeys x
     echo/     Wscript.Sleep 250
     echo/ Next
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 500
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({ENTER})"
     echo/ for j=1 To Len^(StrPwd^)
     echo/     x = Mid^(StrPwd,j,1^)
     echo/     WshShell.SendKeys x
     echo/     Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ Next 
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({ENTER})"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "dir"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({ENTER})"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "exit"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({ENTER})"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({ENTER})"
     ) 

set "_temp_vbs=%temp%\_temp_file_4vbs_.vbs" &  start "" /b !_cmd_!
@"%Windir%\System32\cScript.exe" //nologo "!_temp_vbs!" <nul & del /q /f "!_temp_vbs!" & goto :eof
```